# Adding to a class dynamically

Tags: python

I've created a new class and I'm trying to add to that class dynamically,
I've created a list, that I want to put multiple objects in, then I will iterate over that list in Django (is this the correct way of doing things?)

but I'm getting the below error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 9 arguments (1 given)
```

I know what the error means, I'm just wonder how I go about creating a new instance of my objects and adding to it on the fly easily?

```
### create User Object
class User:
    def __init__(self, Policy, Level, StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime, Name, Mobile):
        self.Policy = Policy
        self.Level = Level
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.StartTime = StartTime
        self.EndTime = EndTime
        self.Name = Name
        self.Mobile = Mobile
    def __init__(self):
        pass    


### Get all the Polices ###
lstOnCall = []
for objPolicy in objPolicyData['escalation_policies']:
    strPolicyName = objPolicy['name']   
    if strPolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:
        for objOnCall in objPolicy['on_call']:
            objUser = User()
            objUser.Policy = strPolicyName
            objUser.Level = objOnCall['level']
            objUser.StartDate = getDate(objOnCall['start'])
            objUser.EndDate = getDate(objOnCall['end'])
            objUser.StartTime = getTime(objOnCall['start'])
            objUser.EndTime = getTime(objOnCall['end'])
            objUser = objOnCall['user']
            objUser.Name = objUser['name']
            objUser.Mobile = getUserMobile(objUser['id'])
            lstOnCall.append(objUser)
print lstOnCall
```

UPDATE:
adding the below works, i just need to know how to print the items now?

```
def __init__(self):
        pass
```

the below

```
for item in lstOnCall:         
    print item()
```

returns

```
    print item()
AttributeError: User instance has no __call__ method
```

Comment: It's `print item` in Python 2 and `print(item)` in Python 3. Not sure what the intent of the parentheses after `item` is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Also, you don't need two inits. If your class takes parameters you should do how James suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't pass them in the instantation, though. You have the data right there; so why not do `objUser = User(strPolicyName, objOnCall['level'], getDate(objOnCall['start'])....)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a dynamic constructor (`def __init__`) for your class so:

```
class User(object):
    __attrs = ['Policy', 'Level', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'StartTime',
               'EndTime', 'Name', 'Mobile']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr, None))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            ['%s: %r' % (attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self.__attrs])
```

- The variable `__attrs` stores the variables names. I used double underscore variable, so that it's inaccessible from extend.

```
user = User()
print(user.__attrs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(user.__attrs)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '__attrs'
```

*Yes, there are other method to access double underscore variable, but no one will do that ;)*

- The function `__repr__` return the `string` by calling `print` or `str`, if the function `__str__` doesn't exist.

Now test it

```
>>> u1 = User(Name='user1')
>>> u2 = User(Name='user2', Policy=1, Level=3)
>>> print(u1)
Policy: None, Level: None, StartDate: None, EndDate: None, StartTime: None, EndTime: None, Name: 'user1', Mobile: None
>>> print(u2)
Policy: 1, Level: 3, StartDate: None, EndDate: None, StartTime: None, EndTime: None, Name: 'user2', Mobile: None
```

If you use my codes, you can print the items in your case so:

```
for item in lstOnCall:         
    print item
```

**Other problem of your code**
There aren't the definition `Function overloading` in Python. You can define **multiple function** with the **same name** in python. But it doesn't make any sense. Only the **last** definition remains in your `class`/`module`. The previous definitions will be **overwritten**. What you are doing with

```
class User:
   def __init__(self, a, b, c):
      ...
   def __init__(self):
      pass
```

is **False**. It works in **Java** or **C#** but not in **Python**. The function `def __init__(self, a, b, c)` will be overwritten. Only the function `def __init__(self)` exists in your class.

Comment: is there a way to print all the items without calling them? im getting     print item()
TypeError: 'User' object is not callable

Comment: Yes. i will add it

Comment: So i have added the function to print all items

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,*args,**kargs):
         if len(kargs)==0 : ''' No param passed '''
            self.Policy = 'Some'
            self.Level = 0
         else:
            self.Policy = kargs['Policy']
            self.Level = kargs['Level']
            [..]

user= User()
user1= User(Policy='Some',Level=13)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i print all the items in the class for viewing now? i tried for item in lstOnCall:         
    print item but i get <__main__.User instance at 0x7f75c02f97a0>

Comment: @AlexW I updated the code. Previous one was not the right way to do. This one works fine in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could set all of the parameters to `__init__` to be `None` by default:

```
def __init__(self, Policy=None, Level=None, etc...):
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the positional parameters of your constructor method to named, optional parameters with a useful default value:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,  Policy=Null, Level=1, 
                 StartDate="2016-01-01", EndDate="2016-12-31", 
                 StartTime="00:00", EndTime="23:59", 
                 Name="UNKNOWN", Mobile=""):
        self.Policy = Policy
        self.Level = Level
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.StartTime = StartTime
        self.EndTime = EndTime
        self.Name = Name
        self.Mobile = Mobile
```